# Как опять победить URLmanager?

Tags: yii2

возник такой вопрос  вот правила

```
'serials/<slug:\w*>' =>  'serial/category/list',
'serials/<id>'   =>  'serial/category/oneserial',
```

пишу такие ссылки

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/serial/category/oneserial','id'=>$model->slug_serial]) //ссылка формируется такая /serials/serial-nazvanie-seriala
 Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/serial/category/list','slug'=>$ct->slug_category])//ссылка формируется такая /serials/сategory
```

но если добавить тире к примеру /serials/nazvanie-сategory то в адресной строке получаю serials?slug=nazvanie-category пытался решить так

```
'serials/<slug:\w*>' =>  'serial/category/list',
'serials/<slug:[\w_\-]+>' =>  'serial/category/list',
'serials/<id>'   =>  'serial/category/oneserial',
```

теперь вот /serials/nazvanie-сategory  это получается хорошо но вот этот адрес  /serials/serial-nazvanie-seriala теперь использует тоже второе правило и парсит на этот адрес serial/category/list что выбрасывает на главную страницу если честно 1 я не понимаю почему и 2 как это исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понял в чем вопрос. Что бы получить адрес вида `/serials/serial-nazvanie-seriala` надо иметь правило:
`'serials/<slug:[\w_\-]+>' =>  'serial/category/list',`
и генерировать так:
`Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/serial/category/list','slug'=>'serial-nazvanie-seriala'])`
Нет необходимости делать два правила.

Вот так:

`'serials/<id:\d+>'   =>  'serial/category/oneserial',
'serials/<slug:[\w_\-]+>' =>  'serial/category/list',`

Comment: нет не о том вопрос как формировать я знаю. совпадают в последнем случае два правила одно ведет на категории второе на сериалы и как отработать ума не приложу

Comment: Что отработать? Проблема в чем заключается? Вы не знаете как контроллер создать, как слаг получить или в чем?

Comment: смотрите я создал правило он с самого верха все проходит нормально  если адрес категории равен /serials/сategory но когда в адрес категрии я вношу тире и хочу получить по идее вот  так /serials/nazvanie-сategory на самом деле получаю вот так serials?slug=nazvanie-category для этого я написал нижнее правило он в таком случае адрес сериала /serials/serial-nazvanie-seriala подтягивает второе правило и меня выкидывает на главную станицу при этом роутинг используеться этот   'serial/category/list' в место  'serial/category/oneserial' при этом передается разный гет параметр в одном случае id в

Comment: в другом slug не понимаю почему и как это исправить.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, потому что в комментариях нельзя переносить строки. Первым у нас идет определение идентификатора. Он числовой и должен проверяться первым, потому что \w означает не только буквы но и цыфры. Ну и потом ваш слаг.

Comment: пробовал тот же эффект при /serials/serial-nazvanie-seriala подтягивает второе правило и меня выкидывает на главную станицу при этом роутинг используется этот 'serial/category/list'